# polars groupby custom function on multiple columns

Tags: python-polars

I have a prediction vs actual dataset over different time periods/segments. I would like to evaluate the prediction using polars groupby, but couldn't figure out what's the best way to do it. In pandas, it would look like

```
df.groupby("seg").apply(lambda x:eval_func(x["true"], x["pred"])
```

Comment: I don't use pandas, are "true" and "pred" other columns? Is `eval_func` vectorized expecting numpy arrays and outputing the same?

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor correct, true and pred are two columns, eval_func can be any metric function such as roc_auc. It returns a scaler .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pl.Expr.map_elements`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_elements.html) on a column having multiple fields defined using [`pl.struct`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.struct.html). In the example below, I compute the [mean absolute percentage error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error) between a time series and corresponding forecast.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "group": ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 3,
    "actuals": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    "preds": [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4],
})
```

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌───────┬─────────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ actuals ┆ preds │
│ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64     ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═════════╪═══════╡
│ A     ┆ 1       ┆ 1     │
│ A     ┆ 2       ┆ 2     │
│ A     ┆ 3       ┆ 3     │
│ B     ┆ 1       ┆ 2     │
│ B     ┆ 2       ┆ 3     │
│ B     ┆ 3       ┆ 4     │
└───────┴─────────┴───────┘
```

```py
def mape(x):
    actuals, preds = x.struct.field("actuals"), x.struct.field("preds")
    return (actuals - preds).abs().mean()

df.group_by("group").agg(
    pl.struct(pl.col("actuals"), pl.col("preds")).map_elements(mape).alias("mape")
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────┬──────┐
│ group ┆ mape │
│ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ str   ┆ f64  │
╞═══════╪══════╡
│ A     ┆ 0.0  │
│ B     ┆ 1.0  │
└───────┴──────┘
```

Note that in this specific example, the result could've been computed relying purely on polars' expression API, which would be more efficient and idiomatic.